# Her beauty and talent is/are the secret of her success

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> a. Her beauty and [her] talent **is**/**are** the secret of her success.
>
> b. The secret of her success **is** her beauty and her talent.
>
> c. Her family and [her] friends **is**/**are** the secret of her success.

What is the correct verb in **a** and **c**? Does including or dropping the second pronoun **her** affect whether or not **is** is correct? (on the presumption that **is** is deemed correct.)

Comment: One is. Many are. _Her beauty is..._ _Her beauty and talent are..._

Comment: @William: The pronoun has nothing to do with the number of members of the set. Does the set  "her beauty and talent" contain more than one thing?

Comment: Her beauty and talent are the secrets of her success.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, very closely related nouns in conjunction may be treated as singular. E.g. "The bow and arrow **is** his weapon." Your instinct that the absence of determiners is relevant is correct, but this is just a hint; you can't use the absence of a determiner on the second noun to definitively determine that the noun phrase is being treated as singular. Ellipsis of the determiner on noun phrases past the first in a list can occur even when the list is conceptualized as plural.

In this case, I wouldn't treat "talent and beauty" as singular. To me, it sounds most natural to use a plural verb after it. In fact, the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beauty%20and%20talent%20are%2C%20beauty%20and%20talent%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeauty%20and%20talent%20are%3B%2Cc0) has no results for "beauty and talent is".

> a. Her beauty and [her] talent **are** the secret of her success.

But keep in mind that in sentences with "be" in English, the verb always agrees with the *subject*. The other noun phrase after the verb is the *predicative complement,* and its grammatical number is completely irrelevant (and [it doesn't have to match the grammatical number of the subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/agreement-in-singular-noun-is-are-plural-noun)). That means that you can't always flip the sentence around without changing the form of the verb. For example, "He **is** me" (*or* "He is I" *in very formal speech*) inverts to "I **am** him" (*or* "I am he" *in very formal speech*). The word "secret" is indisputably singular, so you must use a singular verb when "secret" is the subject of the sentence.

> b. The secret of her success **is** her beauty and her talent.

With "family and friends", I again think plural agreement is what sounds natural:

> c. Her family and [her] friends **are** the secret of her success.

Answer (score 0):

[This source](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) and [this source](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/20-Rules-of-subject-verb-agreement.html) tell us that:

> When deciding which of the helping verbs "is" and "are" to use look at
>   whether the noun is plural or singular.  If the noun is singular use
>   "is", if it is plural or there is more than one noun use "are."
>
> If the subject is thought of as one thing or two things that are so
>   fused as to be thought of together. Sometimes it is two names for the
>   same thing. Then we use "is".

- (Her beauty) and (her talent) are the secret of her success.

Her beauty is the secret of her success and her talent is also the secret of her success.

But if we consider her talent and beauty to a combination (a union) then we use "is"

- (Her beauty and talent) is the secret of her success.

> Note: If we are speaking of a result "to be successful" we use
>   "of her success", but if we speak of a goal she was reaching or is/will be
>   reaching "to become successful" we use "to her success".

Comment: "The secret of her success are her beauty and her talent." is gramatically incorrect.

Comment: Will you provide the link to the source you were using answering the OP's question?

Comment: @Rompey Sure. Btw. I couldn't find the rule that speaks about "The secret of her success are her beauty and her talent." being grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Your  "by the way" has nothing to do with me.

Comment: @Rompey I know, sir! I just didn't want to write a separate comment!